# Making nested attributes work in rails-api only app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, devise, rails-api

I have a rails-api only app in which I have two models.
I am using devise_auth_token for my authentication

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :accounts_attributes
  has_many :accounts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :accounts
  # Include default devise modules.
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
          :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
          :omniauthable
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
  #Deleted ":confirmable," from above
  after_create :assign_member_role

  private
  def assign_member_role
    mr = MemberRole.first # default MR
    Member.create!(user_id: self.id, member_role_id: mr.id)
  end

  def populate_account

  end

end
```

Accounts Model

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

My registration controller is like below:-

```
class RegistrationsController < DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :sign_up_params

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.accounts.build
    # @user.accounts.build.links.build #-> creates one link object you can populate
  end


  def create
    puts "In create"
    params.inspect
    super
  end

  private

    def sign_up_params
      # params.require(:user).permit!(:account_atrributes)
      puts "I am called in sign_up method"
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u|
            # u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :accounts_attributes => :school_name)
            u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :accounts_attributes[:school_name, :line_1, :line_2, :city, :state, :country, :pincode])
          }
      params.permit!
    end


end
```

I am getting the unknown attribute errors as below in my terminal.

```
Started POST "/auth?email=email112@meail.com&password=[FILTERED]&password_confirmation=[FILTERED]&accounts[:school_name]=mjdhs&accounts[:line_1]=asdff&accounts[:line_2]=ijdkjd&accounts[:city]=mum&accounts[:state]=mah&accounts[:country]=IN&accounts[:pincode]=400054" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-07 12:50:31 +0530
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"email"=>"email112@meail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "accounts"=>{":school_name"=>"mjdhs", ":line_1"=>"asdff", ":line_2"=>"ijdkjd", ":city"=>"mum", ":state"=>"mah", ":country"=>"IN", ":pincode"=>"400054"}}
I am called in sign_up method
I am called in sign_up method
In create
I am called in sign_up method
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 106ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)

ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'controller' for User.):
  app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:24:in `create'


  Rendered /home/anjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (4.4ms)
  Rendered /home/anjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.5ms)
  Rendered /home/anjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /home/anjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (19.7ms)
```

I am trying to create a new user with postman in json. I want to accomplish populating the accounts model on every user create.

If i Use the below code in my registraions controller.

```
before_filter :user_params
  puts "hello"

  GET /users/sign_up
  def new

    # Override Devise default behaviour and create a profile as well
    build_resource({})
    resource.build_account
    respond_with self.resource
  end

  def create
    puts "\n\n Testing if the create method can be overriden\n\n"
    puts params.inspect
    params.require(:users).permit!
    super
  end

  protected

  def user_params
    puts "in loop\n\n\n\n"
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u|
      # u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :accounts_attributes => :school_name)
      u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :accounts_attributes[:school_name, :line_1, :line_2, :city, :state, :country, :pincode])
    }
    # params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :accounts_attributes[:school_name, :line_1, :line_2, :city, :state, :country, :pincode])
  end
end
```

I am able to create a new user but cant populate the accounts model. and get unknown params error & parameter missing error as below in my terminal.

```
Started POST "/auth?email=email112@meail.com&password=[FILTERED]&password_confirmation=[FILTERED]&accounts[:school_name]=mjdhs&accounts[:line_1]=asdff&accounts[:line_2]=ijdkjd&accounts[:city]=mum&accounts[:state]=mah&accounts[:country]=IN&accounts[:pincode]=400054" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-07 13:01:33 +0530
hello
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"email"=>"email112@meail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "accounts"=>{":school_name"=>"mjdhs", ":line_1"=>"asdff", ":line_2"=>"ijdkjd", ":city"=>"mum", ":state"=>"mah", ":country"=>"IN", ":pincode"=>"400054"}}
Unpermitted parameter: accounts
in loop





 Testing if the create method can be overriden

{"email"=>"email112@meail.com", "password"=>"password", "password_confirmation"=>"password", "accounts"=>{":school_name"=>"mjdhs", ":line_1"=>"asdff", ":line_2"=>"ijdkjd", ":city"=>"mum", ":state"=>"mah", ":country"=>"IN", ":pincode"=>"400054"}, "controller"=>"registrations", "action"=>"create"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: users):
  app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:65:in `create'


  Rendered /home/anjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (4.5ms)
  Rendered /home/anjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendered /home/anjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered /home/anjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (17.3ms)
```

Comment: well, you should have a own api-controller, for everything, since you want to have controll about your api.

dont use regular controllers for api

Comment: @huanson So should i ditch using any gem for my authentication

Comment: well, that is up to you and your need. just saying you want your own Api Namespace and controllers, where every controller of the api is inherited from your own Api::BaseControler (not from application_controller). 

also you want to inherit from your versions controller, so you can say you release a /api/v2/ where you only changed some behaviour of one model, but everytihng else is still v1. ryan bates had a nice railscast on how to versionize your API